# Java и о всё о ней

Tags: java, терминология

Читаю документацию Java, перевожу, созрели вот такие вопросы:

1. Почему Java язык высокого уровня и как это понять, высокий уровень?

Дальше в документации пишется:

> это язык высокого уровня, который может характеризоваться следующими
>   ключевыми словами:
>
> - Simple (простой)
> - Object oriented (Объектно-ориентированный)
> - Distributed (Распределенный)
> - Multithreaded (Многопоточный)
> - Dynamic (Динамический)
> - Architecture neutral (Архитектура нейтральная)
> - Portable (Портативный) - Переносный
> - High performance (Высокая производительность)
> - Robust (Переводится как крепкий, но я думаю надежный)
> - Secure (Безопасный)

2. Почему простой? В чём проявляется простота?
3. Объектно-ориентированный (понятно)
4. Распределенный, вообще не понятно.
5. Многопоточный (есть слабое понимание)
6. Динамический? Так Java же строго типизированный язык?
7. Архитектура нейтральная - как это понимать?
8. Портативный - То что можно написать программу и она будет работать на windows, unix, macoS, да?
9. Высокая производительность? Как понять у какого языка высокая производительность? Как я знаю в Java высокая производительность достигается тем, что код транслируется в байт-код (поправьте если неправильно)
10. Надежный? Другие языки программирования ненадёжные? В чем проявляется надежность?
11. Безопасный? В чем проявляется? А другие языки небезопасные?

Comment: зачем тебе Java ты же вроде покоряешь фронт и бэк енд?

Comment: Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «[Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)» для прояснения ситуации.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Высокоуровневый язык программирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) — язык программирования, разработанный для быстроты и удобства использования программистом. Основная черта высокоуровневых языков — это абстракция, то есть введение смысловых конструкций, кратко описывающих такие структуры данных и операции над ними, описания которых на машинном коде (или другом низкоуровневом языке программирования) очень длинны и сложны для понимания.
2. Просто попробуйте разработать что-нибудь более-менее серьёзное на C++ и этот вопрос отпадёт.
3. Хорошо, что самая сложная часть понятна.
4. Java изначально создавалась для разработки распределённых систем (то есть работающих сразу на нескольких серверах). В ней эти задачи получаются легче и проще, чем во многих других языках.
5. Грубо говоря, ваша программа может выполнять сразу множество действий одновременно. В некоторых языках этого либо вообще нельзя добиться, либо с ограничениями.
6. Без контекста сложно сказать, что имели ввиду авторы. Вероятно, рефлексию.
7. Это значит, что ваша программа без перекомпиляции будет работать как на 32-битных процессорах ARM, так и на 64-битных процессорах Intel. И на множестве других.
8. Да.
9. Это значит, что не смотря на компиляцию в байт-код, а не машинный код, производительность программ не сильно снижается.
10. А теперь посоветую начать писать что-нибудь более-менее серьёзное на C. Первые лет 5 ваши программы будут сами по себе падать в segmentation fault из-за того, что вы провели неправильную операцию с указателем или не освободили память. Вероятно, повреждая при этом данные. А потом кто-нибудь ещё и напишет эксплойт, который будет эксплуатировать ошибку переполнения стека в вашей программе, позволяющую выполнить произвольный код злоумышленника в вашей системе. Java спроектирована так, чтобы не давать программисту совершать ошибки, на сколько это возможно.
11. Программы на Java работает в изолированном окружении виртуальной машины и не могут навредить системе.

Answer (score -3):

Языки высокого уровня создаются для удобства программистов, в них вся логика удобна для человека, не нужно все запоминать в машинных кодах, как в самом известном языке низкого уровня - ассемблере.

Про безопасность Java подробно расписано [здесь](http://ccfit.nsu.ru/~den/Java/JavaSecurity.html).